# От чего зависит размер приложения после установки?

Tags: android

Возникла довольно интересная ситуация, которую даже после некоторых поисков я не смог объяснить сам себе. У меня есть приложение которое было создано при помощи студии и имеет версию release а не debug. Размер установочного пакета - 1 МБ. Дальше это приложение было установлено на два разных телефона, например - A (HTC Desire 820) и B (Huawei Honor 8).

1. Телефон A - 2 ГБ ОЗУ, Android 6, ПЗУ 16ГБ;
2. Телефон B - 4 ГБ ОЗУ, Android 8, ПЗУ 32ГБ;

После установки вот что мы можем увидеть из занимаемой памяти (ПЗУ):

1. A ~ 3 МБ;
2. B ~ 8 МБ;

Не могу понять почему такая разница. Уже много чего перечитал, про сжатие кода, и тд. и тп. Но вот перед мной лежит два разных телефона и двумя разными показателями. Может проблема в приложении, хотя работает все одинаково и ровно что на одном, что на другом аппарате.

Comment: Что если ты в приложении используешь различные библиотеки где в телефоне А андроид 6 и у него свои ресурсы, а в телефоне В андроид выше и для него функционал библиотек шире от туда мб и черпает

Comment: возможно вы правы @Keeplod, просто странно это все как-то)

Comment: это java, она всем напихана

Comment: Вряд ли дело в библиотеках - если только в приложении есть нативный код и на телефонах процессоры с разной архитектурой, и то слишком большая разница. А о каких цифрах идёт речь - их же там несколько. _Огласите весь список, пожалуйста_ )) И на обоих ли аппаратах они установлены одинаково во внутреннюю или внешнюю (sd-карту) память?

Comment: @woesss, речь идет о занимаемом пространстве во внутренней памяти, оба раза приложение было установлено во внутреннюю память, все идентично, нативного кода нет)

Comment: Занимаемое пространство (общее) включает в себя само приложение, файл(ы) оптимизированного кода, кеши, базы данных, преференсы, записанные приложением файлы.

Comment: хм... ну я это тоже знаю, бд нет, преференсов тоже нет, получается что оптимизация кода происходит по-разному либо что-то другое отличается.

Comment: Но Вы же наверняка используете библиотеки - они тоже могут что-то писать, кешировать во внутреннюю память. Откройте подробности, посмотрите что занимает память приложение или данные. Поройтесь `Device File Explorer`'ом в подпапках `/data`, обращая внимание на всё, что называется Вашим `package.name`

Comment: да, наверное так и сделаю, посмотрю что сохраняет приложение, но вот вы не первый упоминаете про библиотеки, имеются в виду стандартные либы используемые при создании приложения, или же какие-то кастомные вьюхи например?

Comment: Вопрос некоректен. Размер зависит от многих параметров, которые автором не указаны.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, какие параметры я еще не указал?)  я просто не очень понимаю почему так происходит, и поэтому указал те параметры которые думал помогут отвечающим, если нужно добавить какие-то данние, то я добавлю :)

Comment: Это бесполезное занятие. От версии к версии Андроид ОС меняется процесс установки, компиляции и оптимизации. Все что надо знать разработчику, рассказано например здесь: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdfKNgyT438 На остальное разработчик никак не может повлиять.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Так как марки телефонов умолчали, будем угадывать. Скорее всего на первом телефоне андроид в 32битном режиме, а на другом компиляция в 64 битный код. Обычно (обычно), 64битный код занимает приблизительно в два раза больше памяти. Что собственно и случилось.

Comment: а как узнать в каком режиме android? этого я как-то вообще не знал))

Comment: новые андроиды уже 64битные. Их добровольно-принудительно переводят. Старые - естественно 32 битные. И тут как бы не совсем ось, тут и приложения. А вот как узнать.... это надо разобораться

Comment: тут я не соглашусь, мое приложения на android 4.0.3 весит 3Мб, на android 8 весит 60Мб, android 5 - 9мб, android 9 - 8Мб не думаю что дело в разрядности системы.

Comment: Гадать тут можно много на чем: источник установки, нативные библиотеки, dpi девайсов и т.п.

Comment: Тут есть ещё одно - надо смотреть, а что именно включается в "размер". Может на одном телефоне это только распакованные ресурсы (по размеру экрана!), А на другом ещё и кеш программы с всеми временными программами.

Answer (score 7):

В вашем приложении используются различные библиотеки. И для того,чтобы поддерживать работу на более ранних версиях, они используют разный код.
Т.е на версии 8.0 используется один код, на версии меньше - используется другой код. Ну и соответственно память увеличивается.

Comment: Нет никаких оснований полагать что код используемый Android 8 должен быть объемнее чем для предыдущих версий.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja почему же нет. Возьмем какую-нибудь популярную либу которая использует 2 други либы. И в зависимости от sdk она может использовать ту или иную.